# Drawing skeleton robot consisting of revolute joints in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the following skeleton model of a robot which consists of 4 revolute joints as shown below:

[image]

Below is my attempt to draw it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2px]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  line/.style  = {-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
  circl/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size=#1, fill=black!20},
  deci/.style  = {draw, diamond, minimum width=3mm, aspect=#1, fill=black!20},
  box/.style   = {draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=#1, minimum width=#1,line width=1pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (crca) [circl=6mm]{};
\node (crcb) [circl=4mm, below of=crca, yshift=+2cm, label={[label distance=4mm]135:1}]{};
\node (deca) [deci=2, below of=crcb, label={[label distance=4mm]135:2}]{};
\node (decb) [deci=.5, below of=deca, label={[label distance=4mm]135:3}]{};
\node (decc) [deci=.5, right of=crca, label={[label distance=4mm]135:4}]{};
\node (boxa) [box=6mm, below of=decb]{};
\node (boxb) [box=8mm, right of=decc]{};

\draw [line] (crca) -- (decc);
\draw [line] (decc) -- (boxb);
\draw [line] (crca) -- (deca);
\draw [line] (deca) -- (decb);
\draw [line] (decb) -- (boxa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the code keeps on growing and I guess it could be done in much better ways. Below is the screenshot of the generated PDF:

[image]

**I am looking for a better way to generate the diagram shown [at the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0cJL.jpg) of this question**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `pic`s for most of the stuff, which I would place along the path.

- `pic`s are little pictures that you can define and then use while having the flexibility to rotate them or transform them otherwise. They have the advantage that they are somewhat easier to customize than nodes.
- Placing things along the path has the slight advantage that you draw as you specify the relative positions of things (as opposed to placing things at relative positions and then connecting them in a separate step).
- The nodes at the ends of the path can be brought to the form of the
  screen shot by either using a `chamfered rectangle` or `path picture`.

So the first step is to draw the path, where the `|-` syntax is helpful to draw 90 degree corners. Then one can add the pics via the `pos=...` syntax. They can be rotated and so on. And putting them into `local bounding box`es allows us to access their bounding box anchors, which is used in the loop that adds the blue arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2px]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  line/.style  = {-, draw=black!30, line width=1pt},
  box/.style   = {draw=black!30, rectangle, minimum height=#1,
   minimum width=#1,line width=1pt},
  pics/.cd,
  dimmy/.style={code={
  \draw[black,line width=1pt,fill=gray!50] (0,0.5) -- (0.4,0) -- (0,-0.5) -- (-0.4,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[black,line width=1pt] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5);
  \fill[red] (-30:0.2) -- (-150:0.2) -- (90:0.2) -- cycle;
  }},
  cilly/.style={code={
  \draw[black,line width=1pt,fill=gray!50]  (0,0)  circle (0.5);
  \draw[black,line width=1pt,fill=white]  (0,0)circle (0.3);
  \draw[line width=2pt,red,-{Triangle[bend,length=2pt,width=3.5pt]}] (270:0.4) arc (270:90:0.4);
  }} 
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line] 
(0,0) node[box=8mm,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={south west,
south east},chamfered rectangle xsep=2pt,below] (b1) {}|- ++ (0.8,0.2) |-
++(-1.6,0.75) 
pic[pos=0.75,local bounding box=d1]{dimmy} |- ++ (0.8,0.75)
|-  pic[pos=0.175,rotate=-90,local bounding box=d2]{dimmy} ++ (3.5,2)
pic[pos=0.5,local bounding box=c1]{cilly}
pic[pos=0.75,local bounding box=d3,rotate=180]{dimmy}
-- ++ (0,0.2) node[above,box=8mm,path picture={
\draw[line] ([yshift=-1mm]path picture bounding box.north west)
-- ([yshift=-1mm]path picture bounding box.north east);
\draw[line] ([yshift=1mm]path picture bounding box.south west)
-- ([yshift=1mm]path picture bounding box.south east);}] (b2){}; 
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {d3.north,c1.north west,d2.west,d1.west}
{\ifnum\Y=2
\draw [latex-,blue,shorten <=-5pt] (\X) -- ++ (-0.5,0.5) 
node[above left=-2pt,black]{\Y};
\else
\draw [latex-,blue,shorten <=2pt] (\X) -- ++ (-0.5,0.5) 
node[above left=-2pt,black]{\Y};
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! The code is a bit complicated to understand. Can you please provide more explanation?

Comment: @RaviJoshi I added some explanations. It is always hard to explain things because I do not know what part you wish to be explained.

Comment: Thanks again. Appreciate it. Can you provide an explanation for `foreach` loop where you are counting variable `Y`?

Comment: `count=\Y` makes `\Y` to count the item in a `\foreach` loop. Since you wanted to have the numbers 1 to 4 appearing, this is a natural object to use here. So the loop runs over anchors, `\Y` counts them, and then the arrows are attached. For the circle, i.e. item number 2, there is a relative shift which is different from the other items, which is why I put the `\ifnum` there.